# Error while importing into SQL instance using .sql file

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

```
 def import_sql()

      #
      # Authtication completed
      # Authenticated obj = sqladmin
      #
       
      sql_import=Google::Apis::SqladminV1beta4::ImportContext.new
    
      sql_import.database='postgres'
      sql_import.file_type ='SQL'
      sql_import.import_user ='postgres'
      sql_import.uri='gs://sample-bucket-name/sample.sql'
      
      operation=sqladmin.import_instance(instance_name,sql_import)
    
      end
```

I am getting an error message:

> Invalid request: One and only one file path must be specified when
> importing data

I have only specified one path. Not sure where this error is coming from

Comment: Okay I am not that familiar with this process but it looks like your arguments might be off according to the documentation for [`Google::Apis::SqladminV1beta4::SQLAdminService#import_instance`](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-api-client/latest/Google/Apis/SqladminV1beta4/SQLAdminService.html#import_instance-instance_method). It appears based on the signature that the arguments in this case should be `import_instance(project_id,instance_id,import_instances_request_object )` where `import_instances_request_object ` is...

Comment: ... `Google::Apis::SqladminV1beta4::ImportInstancesRequest.new(
                           import_context: sql_import)`